# Send email using mail hangs - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, command-line, email, ubuntu-14.04, email-client

I have try to send email using ubuntu shell and when I execute the below, session is getting hanged. Kindly help me on this.

> echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" abc@gmail.com

After some time below message is throwing from the terminal.

> mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

Comment: post the output of `echo "hello world" | mail -v -s "a subject" abc@gmail.com` (notice the `-v` after `mail`).

Comment: `echo "hello world" | mail -V -s "a subject" dasith9@gmail.com
mail (GNU Mailutils) 2.99.98
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.`

Comment: No, it has to be `-v` not `-V`, small letter 'v' not capital one:

Comment: thanks for the support. This is what I am getting
`mail: invalid option -- 'v'
Try 'mail --help' or 'mail --usage' for more information.`

Comment: ok one more time - the whole command as it should be entered in terminal: `echo "hello world" | mail -v -s "a subject" dasith9@gmail.com mail`

Comment: Still Same :(

`mail: invalid option -- 'v'
Try 'mail --help' or 'mail --usage' for more information.`

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, gnu mail has no 'verbose' option... You can insert the line `set verbose` in your `~/.mailrc` (create it if does not exist) then delivery details will be printed on screen - there should be some helpful information.

Comment: I have just add `set verbose ` using vi. Still same. Can you guide me on this :(

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose why `mail` fails, try the following:

- open `~/.mailrc` in your editor
- make sure it contains line `set verbose`
- save and exit
- try `echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" your@addres.com`

You should see detailed output - mine looks like this:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# echo "test" | mail -s "test" rafal@(...)
WARNING: local host name (vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64) is not qualified; see cf/README: WHO AM I?
rafal@(...)... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4.1ubuntu1; Thu, 28 Jul 2016 10:43:54 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
250-vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64> SIZE=209  AUTH=vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
250 2.1.0 <vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<rafal@(...)>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <rafal@(...)>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <rafal@(...)>... Connecting to (...). via esmtp...
050 220 (...) ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
050 >>> EHLO vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
050 250-(...)
050 250-PIPELINING
050 250-SIZE 10240000
050 250-VRFY
050 250-ETRN
050 250-STARTTLS
050 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
050 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250 DSN
050 >>> STARTTLS
050 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
050 >>> EHLO vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
050 250-(...)
050 250-PIPELINING
050 250-SIZE 10240000
050 250-VRFY
050 250-ETRN
050 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
050 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250 DSN
050 >>> MAIL From:<vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64> SIZE=467 AUTH=<>
050 250 2.1.0 Ok
050 >>> RCPT To:<rafal@(...)>
050 >>> DATA
050 504 5.5.2 <vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname
050 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
050 >>> RSET
050 250 2.0.0 Ok
050 <vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64>... Connecting to local...
050 <vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64>... Sent
250 2.0.0 u6SAhslg010491 Message accepted for delivery
rafal@(...)... Sent (u6SAhslg010491 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 closing connection
```

look for any errors - in my case there were these two lines:

```
050 504 5.5.2 <vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname
050 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
```

so the mail was rejected because my host does not have a fully-qualified hostname.

**edit:** you can also check `/var/log/mail.log/` and `/var/mail/<yourusername>` if there is any useful information about errors.

Comment: This is my mailrc

`root@dig:/# cat ~/.mailrc
set verbose
root@dig:/# `

After adding the above I have executed the below

`echo "hello world" | mail -v -s "a subject" dxxx@abc.com`

I got the below error

`root@diginapp-preprodction:/# echo "hello world" | mail -v -s "a subject" dasitha@duosoftware.com
mail: invalid option -- 'v'
Try 'mail --help' or 'mail --usage' for more information.
root@dig:/# cat ~/.mailrc
set verbose
root@dig:/# `

Comment: Sorry my bad again, try without -v: `echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" your@addres.com` - amended my answer.

Comment: This is what I am getting.

`mail: sendmail (/usr/sbin/sendmailn
mail: mu_mailer_send_message(): using From: root@diginapp-preprodction.c.digin-preproduction.internal
mail: exec /usr/sbin/sendmail argv: /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f root@diginapp-preprodction.c.digin-preproduction.internal -t
mail: Sending headers...
mail: Header: Subject: a subject
mail:
mail: Header: To: <dasitha@duosoftware.com>
mail:
mail: Header: X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.98)
mail:
mail: Header:
mail:
mail: Sending body...
mail: /usr/sbin/sendmail exited with: 0
mail: `